# How to make MediaWiki account registrations only allow unique emails?

Tags: mediawiki

How can I set it so that MediaWiki will not allow a single email address to create multiple accounts? A spambot just created 5 accounts with a single email.

I've looked for configuration settings or extensions, but haven't been able to find one.

A related issue to this is the annoying creation of spam accounts with usernames similar to **JameeiohpbrxvlsHeadlon**.

Spam prevention measurements work quite well, as no actual spam articles are created, but only spam accounts. I have TorBlock, ConfirmEdit and SimpleAntiSpam installed to prevent spam accounts from being created, but this appears to fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not likely to be a very effective anti-spam strategy. Most spambots smart enough to register accounts with valid e-mail addresses are likely also smart enough to try a new address if the registration fails.

Personally, I've found the most effective anti-spam solution for small wikis to be [ConfirmEdit](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aConfirmEdit) with [QuestyCaptcha](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aQuestyCaptcha).  Just configure ConfirmEdit to require a CAPTCHA for account creation, so that you won't get spam accounts.  The questions don't need to be hard to answer — indeed, they can be absolutely trivial, as long as they're unique to your site.

---

That said, you *could* do what you suggest by writing an [AbortNewAccount hook](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/AbortNewAccount) to look up the user's e-mail address in the database and fail if you find a match, something like this (untested!):

```php
$wgHooks['AbortNewAccount'][] = 'disallowDuplicateEmails';

function disallowDuplicateEmails( $user, &$message ) {
    $email = $user->getEmail();
    if ( !$email ) return true;  // allow empty e-mail

    $dbr = wfGetDB( DB_SLAVE );
    $name = $dbr->selectField( 'user', 'user_name',
                               array( 'user_email' => $email ),
                               __METHOD__ );
    if ( $name !== false) {
        $message = wfMessage( 'signup-dup-email', $email, $name )->text();
        return false;
    }
    return true;  // no match
}
```

You'll also need to create the system message page `MediaWiki:signup-dup-email`, with content something like this:

```
The e-mail address <tt>$1</tt> is already used by [[User:$2|$2]].
```

Note that there are at least two potential issues with such a check:

- It can allow people to "fish" for e-mail addresses of your users (something that MediaWiki normally treats as private information) by trying to register a new account with an address they suspect might belong to an existing user.  This could be somewhat mitigated by omitting the username from the error message, but that would still leak the information that *someone* is using the address.
- The code above doesn't check whether the address has been confirmed or not (and checking that would rather defeat its purpose, unless you also require all users to confirm their e-mail address), and so a malicious person could prevent someone else from registering with their e-mail address by creating a dummy account with the same address.

However, getting around the check would actually be rather easy, since a) it checks for an exact match, so e.g. just changing the capitalization of the host name would be enough to make the check pass, and b) it doesn't prevent users from changing their e-mail address to whatever they want *after* registering, anyway.  Both of these holes *could* be blocked, but it would require more effort.

Comment: This will not stop creating the account, since the "AddNewAccount" hook is ran **after** the creation has completed.

You would want to use the "AbortNewAccount" hook to cancel the account creation

Comment: Oops, I indeed had the wrong hook name in the code. Fixed. Thanks, @Gregra!